# Saving multiple lines of text in Firestore with Flutter

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I am making a note keeping page for my app which has the ability to edit a note title and the note itself.

While using Flutter and Firestore I ran into this problem:

I can't find any way to create something like a TextField which would support multiple lines of text and I don't know how I could store that data in Firestore.

**The edit note page code**, currently only reading from Firestore:

```
class EditNotePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot document;
  EditNotePage({
    Key key,
    this.document
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditNotePageState createState() => _EditNotePageState(document);
}

class _EditNotePageState extends State<EditNotePage> {
  final DocumentSnapshot document;
  _EditNotePageState(this.document);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var textFieldTitleController = new TextEditingController(
        text: document['title']
    );
    var textFieldNoteController = new TextEditingController(
        text: document['note']
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit note'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: textFieldTitleController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Title'
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: textFieldNoteController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Note'
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Firestore structure:**

> users > "userUID" > notes > "note" > title (as string) and note (as
>   string)

This would be especially important when making a text editing application or saving long texts written by the user.

Any ideas for solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution, Flutter's text field has a maxLines parameter, feed it with null or the number of lines you want and it will seamlessly be stored in Firebase with no formatting problems whatsoever.